# Response.write() works sync or async?

Tags: node.js

I got 2 functions, something like this:

```
function sendData(data){
    console.log("Sending data")
    response.write()
    console.log("End of data")
}
funcion sendTable(){
    database.each(query, function(){
        //Creating the table to send.
    },function(){
        //When the each ends, completion callback
        console.log("Sending table")
        response.write(table)
        console.log("End of table")
    })
}
```

And then i call the functions

```
sendData("<div>Before table</div>")
sendTable()
sendData("<div>After table</div>")
```

In my code actually they work synchronous (i found the way), so the outpout in the console is something like:

```
Sending data
End of data
Sending table
End of table
Sending data
End of data
```

So, ok, i think my code works, but in the browser i get a wrong order:

```
Before table
After table
/The table/
```

Somebody can explain this to me?, response.write() actually works syn or async?,
but, why the console show the messages in order and the "client" gets data in desorder? Thank you.

Comment: You are using the same response object so its perfectly synchronous. The rendered output is html i guess. Could you paste it? Its not some css issue that the table cant fit between?

Comment: simply reading this pseudo code i cannot explain what you are observing. Even if writing to the network is inherently asynchronous, write() sequence cannot be re-ordered. A complete example (not in pseudo code) could help.

Comment: By the way you should use promises because the log output is confusing as you sending response in the database callback and the end of table should preceed it in almost every cases

Comment: Actually i'm not write the call of the 3 function, an user write the code in a file, then i read the code line by line --> Read line, stop input stream, analize code (With VM)), read line... The output is plain HTML